# What is the meaning of Annie words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Annie is talking to his fake Dad & telling him about his real Dad character during wedding anniversary before Annie's mother

> Annie: Dad always does something really special for the anniversary.
>
> Fake Dad: Like what?
>
> Annie: One year **he had a star named after her**.
>
> Fake Dad: **He had a star named after her**? Well, that's nice, but isn't
>   that a little... corny?

What do you mean **star named after her** means?

---

Is Annie saying her real dad calls her wife with star names during their Anniversary?

for example: Hi, Miss Beauty Proxima Centauri.

Comment: See [this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/name-after).

Comment: Also, a minor point, to *have* a star named after someone means that he arranged for the star to be given the name. He had the power to instruct others to name the star according to his wishes.  Compare: "He *had* his car washed".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Your comment is unclear & confusing, please don't use complex words.

Comment: There is not even one complex word in @Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment! What words do you think are "complex"? They are all common, simple words in English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**To name somebody/something after somebody/something**" means "to give someone or something the same name as another person or thing" ([Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/name-sb-sth-after-sb-sth))

Answer (score 1):

Give her name to the star.

`I will name a star after you` is an other way of saying `I will give the star your name.`

Answer (score 0):

Millions of stars have been catalogued, but only about a thousand are named.  There exist companies that will sell you the right to name one of the others.  Such registrations are not recognized by the International Astronomical Union, and nobody pays any attention to them, as far as I know; but it is a sentimental gesture.  So: Annie's Dad, to honor his wife, paid one of these companies to put her name in their book.